# Where to set the class members in Python?

Tags: python, class, members

Where is it better to declare the class members in Python if I'm not going to initialize them through parameters? In `__init__` or just under the `Class` declaration?

Ex:

```
class A():

    def __init__(self):
        self.__variable = 0

class B():
     __variable = 0
```

And if I went to initialize some and not the others? Is it better to put all in `__init__` or just the ones that are going to be initialized through parameters?

Ex:

```
class A():

    __variable1 = 0

    def __init__(self, variable2):
        self.__variable2 = variable2

class B():

        def __init__(self, variable2):
            self.__variable1 = 0
            self.__variable2 = variable2
```

Justify your answers please.

Cheers and thanks.

Comment: Please provide specific example

Comment: Examples haven been added